# scatter graph + line graph in ios-Charts

Tags: ios, ios-charts

Hi i need a graph as attached for ios. I am using ios-Chart library(swift alternative of MPAndroidChart) for swift .
I have managed to get these points on the graph using the scatter graph. But i couldn't figure out how will i connect the two vertical points. Any help or early response will be appreciate able.

my current code is :

```
func drawChart(dataPoints:[String] , value1 :[Double] , value2:[Double])
    {
        var dataEntries1:[ChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value:value1[i] , xIndex : i)
            dataEntries1.append(dataEntry)
        }

        var dataEntries2:[ChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value:value2[i] , xIndex : i)
            dataEntries2.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let dataSet1 = ScatterChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries1, label: "Value1" )
        dataSet1 .setColor(UIColor.blueColor())
        let dataSet2 = ScatterChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries2 ,label: "Value2")
        dataSet2.setColor(UIColor.greenColor())

        var bloodPressureDataSets = [ScatterChartDataSet]()
        bloodPressureDataSets.append(dataSet1)
        bloodPressureDataSets.append(dataSet2)

        let barChartData = ScatterChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSets: bloodPressureDataSets)

        bpChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
        bpChart.rightAxis.enabled=false
        //barChart.legend.enabled=false
        bpChart.descriptionText=""
        bpChart.data = barChartData

    }
```

Currently i can see this type of graph using the above code.
[image: Current Graph]

I want to join these two vertical points like the graph below,

[image]

Comment: I am confused what's your problem. You already connected the vertical dots on the same x point in your image

Comment: Hi Wingzero , I have edited my original question. I want to have connected graph but using the above code i can only see the dot on the graph but not the connected lines. Is there any way that i can connect these two points on vertical axis?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at scatter chart renderer, drawDataSet func. You can connect the dots there

UPDATE towards your comments:

first, go to ScatterChartRenderer and locate to

`internal func drawDataSet(context context: CGContext, dataSet: ScatterChartDataSet)`

This is where we calculate the position and draw the shape here

There is a main loop:

```
for (var j = 0, count = Int(min(ceil(CGFloat(entries.count) * _animator.phaseX), CGFloat(entries.count))); j < count; j++)
{
            let e = entries[j]
            point.x = CGFloat(e.xIndex)
            point.y = CGFloat(e.value) * phaseY
            point = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(point, valueToPixelMatrix); 
            ...
}
```

Here's the iteration of the data entries your provide in the dataSet, we just get the xIndex and y value here and convert it to the coordinate on the screen.

So what you can do is to sub class this renderer, override this function to get what you want.

e.g. You want to connect the data entries(the dot) for the same xIndex, you should first iterate each data set to collect all the entries on same xIndex, use `CGPointApplyAffineTransform(point, valueToPixelMatrix)` to convert and use CoreGraphics APIs to draw the line. You don't need to worry about the math, the library already gives you the API to convert between data value and the screen coordinate value. You just focus on how to draw the chart.

Comment: hi can you provide me any sample code or any link ??? Couldn't get my head around to use this function.

Comment: answer updated. If you still don't understand what am I saying, you should look at CoreGraphics first, and walk through line chart renderer to figure out how we draw lines

Comment: Hi Wingzero, do we have this support on the latest charts library. I mean connecting the dots with a line.